# New stovetop appears to be single pole 240

Tags: 240v

I have a new stovetop from Amazon that appears to be single pole 240 system. It has two hot but they are soldered together. Could this be right? Did I buy the wrong thing? It was an Amazon 'special'. There are only three sets of wires and the wiring diagram specifically calls for a240 single pole system. Does that exist in the US?

Comment: Sounds like a non US/Canada stove.  Might not be even legal to use if it does not have the right listings.

Comment: we seem to be getting a lot of these Amazon cooktop questions

Comment: Photos? Model? It's probably junk that's illegal to hook up here but it's hard to be sure without details.

Comment: In the US there is not such thing as single pole 240 Volt